# How to increase open file limit in windows server 2012

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012, openfiledialog

We have an application deployed in the windows server 2012 and I am trying to test the application using JMeter. I get Socketexception while tried to increase the number of users.
I think the issue is open file limit.
I just read somewhere that on windows we can see the limit by entering "net config server" in CMD as the admin user. But couldn't find anything which can help me to edit the limit.

Thanks,
Dhruval

Comment: There are fixed users and connections limits for desktop OS.  Microsoft wants you to buy a server OS for server loads.

Comment: Hi Dave, I am using the Windows server.

Comment: Then you should edit your question -- Windows 10 is a desktop OS :)